# Combine rows based on column till condition is true and apply formula?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The `df`:

```
    Unnamed: 0  Trade Date             Symbol Exchange Segment Trade Type  Qty     Price          Order ID  Trade ID                Time
0          NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO       sell  140  29593.00  1400000000087742  50013671 2019-04-24 09:15:16
1          NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO       sell   20  29592.95  1400000000087742  50013672 2019-04-24 09:15:16
2          NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO       sell   20  29592.90  1400000000087742  50013673 2019-04-24 09:15:16
3          NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO       sell   20  29588.40  1400000000087742  50013674 2019-04-24 09:15:16
4          NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO        buy   20  29576.45  1400000000224462  52308594 2019-04-24 13:55:12
5          NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO        buy  100  29576.45  1400000000224462  52308595 2019-04-24 13:55:12
6          NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO        buy   20  29576.80  1400000000224462  52308596 2019-04-24 13:55:12
7          NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO        buy   40  29576.80  1400000000224462  52308597 2019-04-24 13:55:12
8          NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO        buy   20  29577.00  1400000000224462  52308598 2019-04-24 13:55:12
9          NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO        buy   20  29685.00  1400000033885922  52664935 2019-04-24 14:03:38
10         NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO        buy   20  29685.00  1400000033885922  52664936 2019-04-24 14:03:38
11         NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO        buy   20  29685.00  1400000033885922  52664937 2019-04-24 14:03:38
12         NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO        buy   20  29685.00  1400000033885922  52664938 2019-04-24 14:03:38
13         NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO        buy   20  29686.45  1400000033885922  52664939 2019-04-24 14:03:38
14         NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO        buy  100  29686.55  1400000033885922  52664940 2019-04-24 14:03:38
15         NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO       sell   20  29915.65  1400000048617426  54163123 2019-04-24 15:16:48
16         NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO       sell   20  29915.60  1400000048617426  54163124 2019-04-24 15:16:48
17         NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO       sell   40  29914.55  1400000048617426  54163125 2019-04-24 15:16:48
18         NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO       sell   40  29914.45  1400000048617426  54163126 2019-04-24 15:16:48
19         NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO       sell   20  29914.00  1400000048617426  54163127 2019-04-24 15:16:48
20         NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO       sell   20  29914.00  1400000048617426  54163128 2019-04-24 15:16:48
21         NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO       sell   20  29913.95  1400000048617426  54163129 2019-04-24 15:16:48
22         NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO       sell   20  29913.55  1400000048617426  54163130 2019-04-24 15:16:48
```

I want to check the `Trade Type` in row 0 and if the next row(1) is also of the same `Trade Type` add the quantity `Qty` to the first row and make the `Price` = average of the two prices based on `Qty`.

So on till we hit a different `Trade Type`.

Then do the same thing till the quantity of different `Trade Type` becomes equal to row 0. i.e. the trade is closed. And if there is more quantity we create a new row with leftover quantity.

Expected Output:

```
    Unnamed: 0  Trade Date             Symbol Exchange Segment Trade Type  Qty     Price          Order ID  Trade ID                Time
0          NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO       sell  200  29592.525  1400000000087742  50013671 2019-04-24 09:15:16
1          NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO        buy   200  29576.61  1400000000224462  52308594 2019-04-24 13:55:12
2          NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO        buy  200  29685.92  1400000000224462  52308595 2019-04-24 13:55:12
3         NaN  2019-04-24  BANKNIFTY19APRFUT      NSE      FO       sell   200  29914.475
```

The `Trade ID` `Order ID` `Trade Time` are not very important.

I can do this using for loop and lists but I don't think that is pythonic/pandas way of doing this.

Comment: Do you want to compute the weighted average price for **two** rows of the same type or for the whole block? Why there are two rows of `buy` in the middle?

Comment: @QuangHoang regret the late reply. The two rows of `buy` are there because the first row equals the quantity of row 0 sell. i.e. closes out the position. The third row is a new position. I hope this is clearer.